# Where should a user ask home-and-exercises questions?

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises

> Post Closed as "Not suitable for this site" by Brick, Bob D, John Rennie, BioPhysicist, Jon Custer

The above message is shown for [homework-and-exercises](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises). The message is saying that "Not suitable for this site". So, is there any site of SE where a user can freely ask [homework-and-exercises](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises) questions?

Comment: he can try physicsforums.com, but there are rules on that website on how to ask for HW help.

Comment: @DanielC Yes! I am using that but, I haven't read any rules :( :D

Comment: I like physics forums, they don't have strict homework policy.